# Basic questions about Counting Process

Tags: probability-theory

I am learning Counting Process in my probability course. The following comes from **Sheldon M. Ross*'s *Introduction to Probability Models**:

> If we say that an event occurs whenever a child is born, then $\{N(t),
>  t \geq 0\}$is a counting process when $N(t)$ equals the total number
>   of people who were born by time $t$. (Does $N(t)$ include persons who
>   have died by time $t$? Explain why it must.)
>
> The assumption of independent increments ... would be unreasonable for
>   example (b) (the above 'child born' example). The reason for this is
>   that if in example (b) $N(t)$ is very large, then it is probable that
>   there are many people alive at time $t$; this would lead us to believe
>   that the number of new births between time $t$ and time $t+s$ would
>   also tend to be large.

I am not sure if my argument for the above problem is correct: We only consider the 'birth' of child as an event, so whatever happens to the person after his birth, and as long as the person is born within the time interval of our consideration, we should count it as an event.

For the independent increment part, I simply don't understand what it means. Shouldn't the birth of child be independent of the time interval we are considering? What does the book try to tell us?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you are correct: deaths are not "events" in the given model.

For the second question, they mean that if during one given period of time there are lots of births, then that will increase the likelihood of future births when those first children themselves give birth, whereas if there were few births in the first period there will be fewer "parents" available to give future births. (If these are human births, we're talking about time periods of decades.)